# How many EntityManagers are injected for a given PersistenceContext?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0

I am injecting **EntityManager** objects in stateless **EJB3** beans (which act as **DAO** objects and each provide access to a different database table). Deployment is in **JBoss AS 7**.

I then added code using **System.identityHashCode** in the **EJB3** beans methods to see the various instances of the **EntityManagers** injecting (hoping to see the same instance in all DAOs). E.g. like:

```
@Stateless
public class AFacade {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="foo")
    EntityManager em;

    public List<A> findAll() {
         l.info("entity manager is: "+System.identityHashCode(em)+" class is: "+em.getClass().getSimpleName());
         ...
    }
```

However, what I noticed is that each **DAO** (e.g. **AFacade**, **BFacade** and so on) was injected with a different **EntityManager** (as reported by **identityHashCode**) although the **PersistenceContext** was the same. The implementing class was **TransactionScopedEntityManager** in all cases.

It is not clear to me why this different **EntityManager** objects are injected, whether this is something that should concern me or not. Also, I understand that the EJB3 container may actually inject proxies to the real **EntityManager** so these different instances may actually be proxies to a single **EntityManager**.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are proxies (in fact, I think they are thread safe decorators, rather than proxies) on the real entity managers.

I'm not sure if you know that the EntityManager is a wrapper around a connection. If you wouldn't have this decorator (or proxy), all invocations to that stateless bean would share the same connection (and potentially transaction), which is not what you want.

Answer (score 4):

The injected EntityManagers are proxy generated by the EJB Containers.

For ***Transaction scoped Entity Managers***, each transaction uses a *single separate instance* of ***Provider's Entity Manager***.

When a method call is made to this proxy , container checks ***javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry*** ( this is implemented by EJB Container)  to see if there is a provider EntityManager already created for this transaction. If not, it will create the provider Entity Manager and register it in TransactionSynchronizationRegistry and then delegate the method call to it. If already present, it will simply retrieve the provider Entity Manager an delegate the method call to it.

***Transaction scoped EntityManagers are stateless*** according to the book "Pro JPA2 Mastering the Java Persistence API" by  Mike Keith and Merrick Schincariol (See Chapter 6).

The proxy objects  inserted in each EJB instance object is different, though a single proxy object could have been used because of the stateless nature of Transaction scoped Entity Manager.

Also take a look at : http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/11/am-i-in-the-same-transaction-am-i-using-the-same-persistencecontext/